# How to only return 0, 1 or 2 in pytorch

Tags: python, pandas, neural-network, pytorch

My neural network is supposed to predict a vector of 587 integers. Those integers can only be equal to 0, 1 or 2.

Is it possible to force the network to output a 0, a 1 or a 2 ? SoftMax wouldn't work because not only does it return a value between 0 and 1 but also this value is not necessarily exactly 1. but rather 0.989, etc ...

My neural network is for now very simple :

```
self.l1 = nn.Linear(input_size, hidden_size)
self.relu = nn.ReLU()
self.l2 = nn.Linear(hidden_size, num_classes)
```

and i was wondering if there was a layer corresponding to what I wanna achieve ?

Or should I make 587 neural networks that predict three classes in which case my loss would be a categorical cross entropy and my outputs one-hot vector like [0, 1, 0] to encode 1 and [0,  0,  1] to encode 2 ?

Sincerely

Comment: I would try to address the problem as a multi-label classification problem. Have a look at [this wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multi-label_classification), for a starting introduction.

Answer (score 0):

**Change your output_dims to 587*3 and then run:**

```
probs = output.reshape(587, 3)
dist = Categorical(probs)
output_vector = dist.sample()
```